# Where @font-face saves font files on your computer?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am using @font-face to refer new fonts and it works fine.

My question is: are the font files downloaded to the computer from where my website is being visited or just stored temporarily? They do not get stored in Control Panel -> Fonts.

So is it just browser cache or the computer can get to have to font used in other software like Word etc?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: they're loaded dynamically by the browser for rendering the page. The font file may be CACHED by the browser for possible later reuse within the browser, but  simply referring to a font in a web page is **NOT** going to install that font on your system for permanent use by other apps.

Comment: @MarcB That sort of does make sense as fonts are proprietary (though I can download a font from a website and use it). I wasn't sure about this. Thanks for the explanation. If you move your comment as answer, I can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. When they're used in a webpage the browser just stores them temporarily. You would have to install the font separately for the other uses you mentioned.